# Set breeds still acting like last breed

Tags: netlogo

In this code

```
  breed [turtles1 turtle1]
    breed [turtles2 turtle2]
    
    to setup
      clear-all
      random-seed 1
      
      create-turtles1 5 [set shape "circle" setxy random 30 random 30]
      reset-ticks
    end
    
    to go
      ask turtles1[ 
        print "first" print who
        if any? other turtles1 [ 
        ask  one-of  other turtles1
           [set breed turtles2 set shape "square" print "other" print who]]
      ]
      
      
    end
```

It calls turtles1 and asks them to change the breed of another turtle1. As I've set a random seed, in this case the first turtle1 will be who = 3 and it will cause turtle1 who = 0 to change breed to turtle2. However that turtle2 who = 0 will still get called under the ask turtle1 [] (see the last action - it causes turtle1 who = 1 to change to turtle2).

Is there any way to stop a turtle being called from an ask[] if it changes to a different breed in the above context?

Answer (score 0):

Think I've worked it out - but open to better suggestions.

```
breed [turtles1 turtle1]
breed [turtles2 turtle2]

to setup
  clear-all
  random-seed 1
 
  create-turtles1 5 [set shape "circle" setxy random 30 random 30]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles1[ 
    print "first" print who
    if any? other turtles1 [ 
      ask  one-of  other turtles1 
      [  hatch 1 [set breed turtles2 set shape "square" print "other" setxy random 30 random 30] print who die]]
  ]
  end
```

This hatches a new turtle1, changes it to a turtle2 and then kills off the hatcher.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Netlogo first determines all the agents that will get to act, and then lets them act one by one. Even if you change the properties of the turtles in a way that would mean it would no longer be selected to act if ask was called again, it will still act because it was selected before any changes were made.

The following is an example where you let each turtle check whether or not it still qualifies for the initial conditions when it is called.

```
breed [turtles1 turtle1]
breed [turtles2 turtle2]

to setup
  clear-all
  random-seed 1
  
  create-turtles1 5 [set shape "circle" setxy random 30 random 30]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles1[ 
    if breed = turtles1 [
      print "first" print who
      if any? other turtles1 [ 
        ask  one-of  other turtles1[
          set breed turtles2 set shape "square" print "other" print who
        ] ;end of ask
      ] ;end of if
    ] ;end of if
  ] ;end of ask

end
```

Do keep in mind that with this option, the subsequent turtles might still change the breed of the first turtle as well. That means your model will have some artefacts of order which might be desirable or undesirable. But you should definitely figure out which of the two it is.

Comment: Thanks for that - I think it is easier to follow than my 'hatch - set breed - die' approach